# Use SECEDIT to export "Security Options" from one computer and import on another

Tags: windows-server-2008, security

Can I use secedit.exe to export out the "Security Options" from the local security policy and then import them on another machine?

I'm trying to do this on Windows Server 2008.

**Update**

I just tried with:

```
secedit /export /db C:\andy.db /cfg C:\andy.inf /areas SECURITYPOLICY /log C:\andy.log
```

But it didn't work with error:

```
Warning 2: The system cannot find the file specified.
    Error opening C:\andy.db.
```

Where do I get the DB file from?

Comment: It would appear so from looking at the information available from running secedit /export /? and secedit /import /? at the command prompt.

Comment: Thanks @joeqwerty I'm just trying to figure out to get them to work now :-)

Answer (score 3):

I had to do the same thing a while ago to setup a Server Core system with a security policy. Here are my scratch notes:

**Export:**

```
secedit /export /db secedit.sdb /cfg sctest.inf
```

**Import:**

```
# NOTE: May not work if you're in a read-only directory, 
#       or sctest.inf is read-only
secedit /configure /db secedit.sdb /cfg sctest.inf /overwrite
```